# I wanna handle log in part in tripadvisor but below code doesn't work

Tags: java, web, selenium-webdriver

I tried this,

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
```

Here both the main parent window nad subwindow id's are same.

I want to go to that popup and enter emailID and password

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have found is for popup windows that are another instance of the browser (or browser tabs). The dialog that is popping up when you log in is just a `DIV` based dialog and is actually part of the page. You can tell a couple ways... 1) if you can't drag the popup outside of the browser, then it's part of the page. 2) if it doesn't have the browser app frame around it, then it's (likely) part of the page.

So, what you need is to just find the elements on the page, as you would any other page. In this case, they are inside an `IFRAME` so you will need to switch context to the `IFRAME` before accessing the elements. The code below works.

```
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.link.no_cpu")).click(); // click Log in
driver.switchTo().frame("overlayRegFrame"); // switch to iframe
driver.findElement(By.id("regSignIn.email")).sendKeys(email);
driver.findElement(By.id("regSignIn.password")).sendKeys(password);
```